# avoid writing width of picture manually

Tags: html, css, absolute

I wrote picture width in property class to put price 15 pixels from the right edge of the picture.
Now right works correctly, but if I remove it, price will be placed at 15px from the right edge of page..

html:

```
<div class = "property">
    <img src = "http://preview.byaviators.com/template/realia/assets/img/tmp/property-small-1.png"/>
    <div class = "type">House</div>
    <div class = "price">90 000 €</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.property {
    position: relative;
    width: 270px;
}
.price {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

Can you suggest a way, in which I will avoid writing of picture width and right will work as it should be? Thanks, p.s. [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ht80y82y/)

Comment: Can you explain more or post an image which is shown your problem?

Comment: delete  width: 270px; in https://jsfiddle.net/ht80y82y/ to see my problem. I want avoid it without width

Comment: The problem is that div has width 100% because is block but image is smaller and you want to position based on image dimensions. Try @Nenad Vracar solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/ht80y82y/1/

**CSS**

```
.property {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`div` element(`.property`) has `display:block;` by default. It means the element width will be inherited from its parent. However, you can solve your problem by giving `display:inline-block;` and so on.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/ht80y82y/2/)

Or change `div` to `span`.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/ht80y82y/4/)